# CORS headers in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, cors

I'm having some difficulty with CORS headers not giving me access to fonts in my Wordpress site.

This is the error I get in the console:

*

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v10/0dTEPzkLWceF7z0koJaX1A.woff2.
>   (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)

.*

I've tried the following but to no avail:

- Amending my htaccess. file. Here it is:

  ## Switch rewrite engine off in case this was installed under HostPay.

  RewriteEngine Off

  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php .php5

  DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.php

  ## BEGIN WordPress

  RewriteEngine On
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

          Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

  ## END WordPress

  - Downloading the WP-CORS plugin, which seems to be what I need but the bloody 'Settings' tab doesn't appear!
  - Adding some php into the top of my header.php file, but that doesn't seem to do anything either.

The sit eis hosted on 123-reg so I don't have access to Apache, so sudo a2enmod headers isn't an option either.

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: The problem is not on your server. The CORS header has to be send by the server on which the requested file is. In your case the file is on the google server and they send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header the right way.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I follow - so the problem isn't my end, it's on the Google server when the font is based? Surely that can't be the case?

Answer (score 0):

The server that serves the file gets to chose who gets to request the file. The file you're attempting to request is on Google's server as KIMB-technologies said.

You cannot set CORS for someone else's server. That just wouldn't be nice.

You can read more about CORS from Mozilla over [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).